# Hackerrank: Lucky Number Eight (Dynamic Programming)

Tags: c#, algorithm, programming-challenge, dynamic-programming

[Problem statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w28/challenges/lucky-number-eight)

> Given an n-digit positive integer, count and print the number of subsequences formed by concatenating the given number's digits that are divisible by 8. As the result can be large, print the result modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains an integer denoting `n`.
>
> The second line contains a string describing an n-digit integer.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> · 1 ≤ n ≤ 2 x 10<sup>5</sup>
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print a single integer denoting the count of subsequences of the given number that are divisible by `8`, modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7.
>
> **Sample Input 0**
>
> `3`
>
> `968`
>
> **Sample Output 0**
>
> `3`
>
> **Explanation 0**
>
> The numbers obtained from subsequences of `968` are `9`,`6`,`8`,`96`,`68`,`98`  and `968`. Three of these numbers (i.e., `968`,`96`, and `8`) are divisible by `8`, so we print the value of `3` mod (10<sup>9</sup> + 7) = 3 as our answer.

**My introduction of the algorithm**

The algorithm is a medium level one in the hackerrank contest of week of code 28 from January 9 to 15, 2017. I wrote an algorithm in the contest, and the code has over 300 lines of code, with timeout issue, not efficient.

So I learned to use dynamic programming method to solve the algorithm today. I read the editorial notes on hackerrank first, and studied one of submissions, and then built a frequency table for the sample test case `968` to clear my questions from code reading. And then I wrote the algorithm following the ideas showing in the frequency table, using dynamic programming bottom-up method.

**Hackerrank Editorial Notes**

In this problem, you are given a sequence of digits of length `N`. You have to find the number of non-contiguous subsequences, such that the number formed by their concatenation is divisible by 8.

Observe a bit,

The number is formed by concatenating the non-contiguous subsequences, which implies that the number itself is a subsequence and vice-versa.

So the problem boils down to counting the ways you can make a subsequence divisible by `8`. This can be done by Dynamic Programming.

At any position of the sequence, you need to consider two cases:

1. Concatenate the digit at the position with your current subsequence and move to next position.
2. Leave the digit and move to next position.

The idea can be coded with states: *Current position* and *Remainder of the subsequence modulo* 8.

**Frequency table of sample test case: 968**

I tried to put together a table to illustrate the idea of bottom-up solution using dynamic programming, and call it a **frequency table**, with `3` rows: `9`, `96`, `968`, `8` columns representing all possible remainder of module 8 operation in ascending order, `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`.

At first, the first digit of number `968` is `9`, the possible subsequences of `9` is empty number(none is selected) and `9`. So the remainders are `0` or `1`, since 9 % 8 = 1.

Work on the next digit `6`, so either the digit `6` is not included in the subsequences or is included in the sequence.

For first choice of excluding digit `6`, we just copy the subsequences in last step, two numbers: `0` and `9`,  frequency table row entry: 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

For second choice of including digit `6`, we will include `6` in the subsequences, therefore, we have to iterate the remainder with nonzero values: `0` and `1`. two numbers of `6` and `16`, 6's remainder of module `8` is `6`, and 16' remainder of `8` is `0`. The row entry: 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.

So, combining the above two choices, second row frequency table 2, 1, 0, 0,0, 0, 1, 0.

[image]

So, following the table from left-top corner, row by row, top to down, frequencyTablep[0,0] = 1, 0 can be divisible by 8, even 0 is not a subsequence of 968. We add to the table first, and then later take away 1 from frequencyTable[2,0]. So the numbers obtained from sequences of `968` are `96`,`9`,`968`, `3` is the answer.

C# code passes all test cases on hackerrank online judge.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hackerrank_LuckyNumber8_DP_Studycode
{
    /*
     * Problem statement:
     * 
     * https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w28/challenges/lucky-number-eight
     * 
     * Study dynamic programming solution 
     * 
     * questions on two things: 
     * first value is 1, count[0][0] = 1, why? count 0 as the first digit. see the frequency table. 
     * second, count[n - 1][0] + Module - 1, why? Remove number 0 as the answer. 
     */
    class Program
    {
        private static long Module = 1000000007;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            var number = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

            var frequencyTable = new int[n][];  // subsequences 

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                frequencyTable[i] = new int[8];
            }

            BuildFrequencyTableFromBottomUp(frequencyTable, number, n);

            Console.WriteLine((frequencyTable[n - 1][0] - 1) % Module);
        }

        /*
         * Build frequency table using bottom up method - dynamic programming
         * Design of the algorithm: 
         * At any position of the sequence, you need to consider two cases:
            Concatenate the digit at the position with your current subsequence and move to next position.
            Leave the digit and move to next position.
            The idea can be coded with states: Current position and Remainder of the subsequence modulo 8.
         * 
         */
        public static void BuildFrequencyTableFromBottomUp(int[][] frequencyTable, string number, int n)
        {
            const int SIZE = 8;
            frequencyTable[0][0] = 1;  // ask why here? count 0 as the first digit
            frequencyTable[0][(number[0] - '0') % SIZE]++;

            // build a frequency table - 
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                // subseqences - just ignore the current elment
                for (int remainder = 0; remainder < SIZE; remainder++)
                {
                    frequencyTable[i][remainder] = frequencyTable[i - 1][remainder];
                }

                // iterate each element in the array - go over all possible remainders in ascending order
                for (int remainder = 0; remainder < SIZE; remainder++)
                {
                    long current = frequencyTable[i - 1][remainder];

                    // if the remainder's related count is 0, then no possible subsequences to the nextRemainder
                    // skip the remainder. 
                    if (current == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    int nextRemainder = (10 * remainder + (number[i] - '0')) % SIZE;

                    frequencyTable[i][nextRemainder] = (Int32)((frequencyTable[i][nextRemainder] + current) % Module);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it kind of silly that you receive `n` as the first input and the second input in a `n`-digit number.  I'd think things could be simpler if you just received some input number where you can quickly determine its length to compute `n`.  But I'm guessing that the rules of the contest.

One area of a small bit of inefficiency - as well as naming confusion - is regarding to `number[i] - '0'`.  The truth is `number` is not a number.  It's a string composed of digits, which you trust is valid input since you don't validate it.  That's fine as long as the rules are they absolutely will be passing you an integer as as string.

You can perhaps improve readability and performance somewhat by converting the string of digits to an integer array once, and pass that to `BuildFrequencyTableFromBottomUp`.  This can be something simple like:

```
private static int[] ToIntegerArray(string stringOfDigits) => stringOfDigits.Select(digit => digit - '0').ToArray();
```

Don't know how many total inner loops you are going through.  Usually if it's a few hundred thousand, it would not be a factor on performance.  Now if it were several billion, converting to an integer array first would have measurable improvement.

You would then need to change the relevant code in your method.

Comment: I like your review. Very good review. You made good observation of a not-so-good argument name in the function BuildFrequencyTableFromBottomUp, name should be better to be replaced using stringOfDigits, and also redundant calculation of conversion char to integer.

Comment: I wrote some frequency table explanation, and wondered if the name of frequency table makes sense or not here. And also the explanation of 968, go over first two digits to warm up the idea of constructing a dynamic programming method. I do like to hear your comment as well.